# Retrieving proportion of pixels in R

Tags: raster, r, statistics

I'm trying to retrieve the following pixel statistics:

1. Proportion of zero value pixels:

   `[nº of zero value pixels / (total nº of pixels - nº of NA pixels)]`
2. Proportion of pixels smaller than 3rd quartile (= 0.75):

   `[nº of pixels < 3rd quartile / (total nº of pixels - nº of NA pixels)]`

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(raster)  
f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")  
r <- raster(f) #r is the object  
plot(r)  
summary(r)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of doing this is to work with the matrix:

```
#Raster to matrix
r_matrix<-as.matrix(r)
#Proportion of zero value pixels
P0<-length(which(r_matrix==0))/(length(r_matrix)-length(which(is.na(r_matrix))))
#Proportion of values < 3rd Quantile     
value=as.numeric(summary(as.vector(r_matrix))[5])#position of the 3rd quantile value
P3<-length(which(r_matrix<value))/(length(r_matrix)-length(which(is.na(r_matrix))))
```